# Application crashes after updating to Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, uivisualeffectview

I have recently updated my Xcode, after updating the Xcode I am facing a crash.
Here the crash happening

```
    UIBlurEffect *blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    UIVisualEffectView *vsview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];


    _bgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    _bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8];
    _bgView.alpha = 0;
    _bgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *buttonTap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

    buttonTap2.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    vsview.frame = _bgView.bounds;
    _bgView = vsview;
    [_bgView addGestureRecognizer:buttonTap2];


    _normalImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    _normalImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _normalImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    _normalImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _normalImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.f;
    _normalImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-10, -10);



    _pressedImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    _pressedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    _pressedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    _normalImageView.image = _normalImage;
    _pressedImageView.image = _pressedImage;


    [_bgView addSubview:_menuTable];
```

Where `_bgView` is `UIView` and `_menuTable` is `UITableView`;

the logs stating the following error message.

> Assertion failure in -[UIVisualEffectView
>   _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.34.4/UIVisualEffectView.m:1558
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ';
>   layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize:
>   {281.25, 72}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> has been added as a
>   subview to ; layer = >. Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view
>   itself, instead add them to the -contentView.

Before updating he Xcode it is working fine.

Comment: And what are you wxactly asking about? Because wverything you need to fix your issue is in the description of the crash you provided.

Comment: I tried to add the [_bgView.contentView addSubview:_menuTable]; but If I am trying to that the  _bgView has an background transpenrancy view and it is not displaying.

Comment: Well, actually you setting the `alpha = 0` on `_bgView` shouldn't matter he way your code is written, because you assign `vsView` to that variable later so everything before that gets discarded. Is there a way you could provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not adding anything as child to the visual effect view

Answer (score 0):

This error message is caused by trying to add a subview to the `UIVisualEffectView`.

Change

```
UIVisualEffectView *vsview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];
[vsview addSubview:newView];
```

to

```
UIVisualEffectView *vsview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];
[vsview.contentView addSubview:newView];
```